# What is the maximum size supported for ArcGIS Server Workgroup?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

I have a database with a size of 200 gb and expect to grow near of a 1 Tb in two years.

It´s possible to install an ArcGIS Server Workgroup 10.2 with this size of information? I´m afraid not understand the information about the size supported for ArcGIS Server Workgroup I saw that was 4gb (very poor) but in  functionality matrix Esri said 4gb but show this:

> At any given time, the firm may be using 3 GB of vector data stored in
>   SQL Server Express and configured for concurrent edits from three
>   desktop seats, over 50 GB of imagery stored as TIFF files, and 15 GB
>   of data stored in file geodatabases.

It´s possible that the capacity of the database is different for the maximum size of ArcSDE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 10Gb workgroup geodatabase storage limit is intrinsic to SQL-Server Express 2012, as stated in the [Esri Documentation (p5)](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/~/media/Files/Pdfs/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-server-functionality-matrix.pdf):
[image]

200Gb is 190gb too large for a workgroup geodatabase.  1Tb will be 990Gb too large.

Note that 1Tb is an awful lot of vector data.  If you have imagery *in files on disk*, then they are not part of the storage capacity limit (only the data actually in Express is limited, as the example you cite explains).

Comment: Thanks Vince, I agree that 200gb is too large for vector data I think that the most would be raster data. But if you load raster data in arcsde like a raster catalog, mosaic,...this would be part of the SQL Server Express?

Comment: Databases were never a great place to put raster data, though when that capability was introduced at 8.0, that was the best way to obtain high-performance tiling. The introduction of cached tiling in ArcGIS Server put the first nails in the "raster in database" coffin. File-based mosaic datasets have been the focus of raster development for a long time now, so I don't even think about loading rasters in databases, but yes, raster storage in database tables would quickly fill the 4Gb (2008) or 10Gb (2012) Express limits.